# Deleted answer still visible?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

The following scenario happened to a question of mine today:

- I asked a question to a topic I'm pretty new to.
- Someone answered the question, it absolutely satisfied my points, so I upvoted and accepted it.

But a few minutes later he got heavily downvoted because (as I understand it) the way he explained the points were completely wrong and they said his words just show he has no clue about the topic.  So he deleted his answer, which made me sad as I thought it will be lost.

But it wasn't.  His answer is still in the question. It has a weak colour, as an answer has of my own after I deleted it. But why? Is this just to me, as I'm the one who upvoted it? Or is it because at the point he deleted it, it was the accepted answer?  And is this just visible to me?  Or anyone can still see it?

And I also noticed he still has the +2 rep he got left from his answer (after downvoting) so is this really a deleted answer?  What's going on?

Comment: Could you link to the question?

Comment: You can't delete an accepted answer. And your today's questions don't contain deleted posts.

Comment: @juergend The author can't delete it on their own, a mod can, and it can be deleted as a result of enough flags.

Comment: I was refering to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19313642/2003898 and it wasn't deleted as David Robinson allready said, I jsut missunderstood the weak colour.

Comment: Well, it got a delete vote now - two more and it will be really gone. :)

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard What are you talking about?

Comment: @Zaibis [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ASe.png). It means 10K+ user has cast a delete vote on that answer, and three of those votes will cause the answer to get deleted.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard eah, But which answer are you talking about? And who are you talking to? Or did ou just want to tell us something interesting?:D

Comment: @Zaibis never mind, you missed my point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313642/712603) on your question: that answer has not been deleted. The text is shown in a light gray to indicate that it is heavily downvoted: deleted questions have a greyish red background. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22185/176330) for a description of what each color means:

> Answers with score of -3 or lower get light gray text color and so are all comments made on such answers

Indeed, it is not possible for a user to delete an answer while it is the accepted answer.

Comment: Ah, so he didn't delete it. Thanks for fast info and side info whcih I had asked any when also for.